does DALL-E api use Microsoft account info while generating responses?
I have read some work regarding occupational gender bias in AI image generation and it seemed. According to my research, tools like DALL-E generated more images of men when trying out for images with high paying jobs (lawyers, doctors etc). However, when I tried it via my openAI account, the results were shockingly different. I am a female, which probably reflects in my account info. When I generate images of these professions, I get almost all females. Which is quite opposite to what I get when I try Stable diffusion locally. Is there any proof/study that shows that the DALL-E api might use our account info while generating responses?
